# How can I synchronize a HashMap while allowing for simultaneous reader threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm making use of the following `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Three different `Runnable`s running in separate threads will read from `hm`, while a fourth thread's `Runnable` will add and remove key/value entries from the map. As per [the Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), I should syncronize access to this map whenever multiple threads may concurrently interact with it. However, for performance reasons, I don't want the three reader threads to block each other since they're simply reading from the map. I only want blocking to occur when the fourth thread is adding/removing map entries. From my understanding, calling `Collections.synchronizedMap(...)` will synchronize *any* type of access to the map. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `ConcurrentHashMap`, or use a ReaderWriterLock yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> should synchronize access to this map whenever multiple threads may concurrently interact with it. However, for performance reasons, I don't want the three reader threads to block each other since they're simply reading from the map.

Although the readers don't need to block, you do need synchronize memory on *both* on reads *and* writes otherwise the readers could get a partially updated map which could generate an exception.   See the [tutorial on memory synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html).

The hard part about multithreaded programming is that each thread has its own local CPU memory cache which is then synchronized with central memory.  A thread that is just reading will *not* see updates that were made by synchronized writes.  Even worse, they could see partial updating of a map's internal memory which would cause exceptions.

To synchronize your map you should either wrap it in a `Collections.synchronizedMap(...)` call or (as @SLaks mentions in comments), use the [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) which was built for multiple readers/writers.  @SLaks also mentions the `ReaderWriterLock` but the CHM would be more efficient and a lot less code to maintain.

More specifically, in terms of "blocking", CHM partitions the map and does an excellent job of handling multiple readers and writers with minimal blocking.  For example, the only time that getting from a CHM actually does a lock is when an object is looked up that was inserted into the map immediately before the `get` call.

I would not worry about the performance of CHM unless a profiler has told you that it is a performance problem.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. He doesn't want reader threads to block each other. It is possible: see @SLaks' comment.

Comment: @EJP the `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't block concurrent readers - at least it makes a best attempt not to.

Comment: I've made it more plain @EJP that he has to have some sort of memory synchronization but he _can_ avoid a synchronize "block".

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements (and the frequency of writes compared to reads), a [CopyOnWriteMap](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-util-concurrent/wiki/CopyOnWrite%20Maps) could be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The level of synchronization required really depends on your specific use case.  @SLaks's recommendation to use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) would work **as long as** you don't require one read from the Map to the next operate on the same data.  For instance:

```
if (instance.containsKey("foo")) {
    System.out.println(instance.get("foo"));
}
```

can fail as the ConcurrentHashMap can change between the two function calls.  If you require such guarantees, you should use a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html), as you can keep the Map locked for the duration of the reads/writes.  For instance, the same code above would look like:

```
rwlock.readLock().lock();
try {
    if (instance.containsKey("foo")) {
        System.out.println(instance.get("foo"));
    }
} finally {
    rwlock.readLock().unlock();
}
```

(in this case, instance can be any implementation of Map<>, it doesn't have to be a ConcurrentHashMap).

Comment: That's not the best example since it should be get() and then a test against `null`.

Comment: @Gray Are you saying it should check against null, as the map could contain a null value, or that it should check against null (in the first case) to avoid the race condition?  I assumed in the examples that map didn't contain null values, and if the map can have null values a check is necessary.  Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: I'm just saying that there are good examples of needed to do 2 operations on a CHP so that you need a lock.  Testing for contains and then getting is not a good example because you could do a get first and then test for contains being `== null` or not.

Comment: @Gray Yes, it is very simplistic, but you may not be able to do the null check, as you data may have null values (though the example would of course fail in that case, assuming you don't handle that condition).  I tried to keep the example simple, as unnecessary complications can cloud the idea.

Comment: CHM doesn't allow `null` values @MJD but I understand what you mean.

Comment: Whoops, I read the documentation too quickly! I thought it had only meant keys couldn't be null.  Thanks for pointing that out.